# Identify Book - 1st chapter about a woman awaking after a battle in a snowy landscape

Tags: story-identification, books

I stopped by the library one day to pick something up and I randomly started reading this book while waiting - I've only read a couple of pages and I can't remember the title or author. I believe it is set in a space-travel era where a woman wakes up around corpses covered in snow which she introspectively claims to have killed.

She finds another victim along the road and continues until she ends up at a statue/monument where she removed her uniform and lay down to freeze to death.

Any help would be appreciated in finding the title of the book - I apologize if I got some of the details wrong, this was quite some time ago. And no spoilers please, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would be “Stealing Light“ by Gary Gibson. In the First chapter the Protagonist Dakota wakes up in a battlefield and tries to kill herself by stripping off her suit. She is rescued in time by friendly forces. The book is the First in a trilogy (the others being Nova War and Empire of Light.

Comment: That's it, thank you very much Tomm :)

Answer (score 3):

Path of the Fury by David Weber

Comment: Can you please provide specific details on how this book matches the request? Thanks

Comment: It's similar to what I've read but I'm quite sure it isn't it - there was no dialogue or other interacting characters in the first couple scenes I've mentioned and Chapter 1 of Path of the Fury jumps right into a scene.